# Python newbie questions about multiprocessing

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, process-pool

Python newbie question

I've been using Python for about a week and I'm focusing on speed so I've come up with a test project to learn about multithreading and multiprocessing.

I have a table of 5000 empolyee records that need to be 'analyzed'
I have a table of 50 tests (in user-defined python code)
I have a blank table for storing the test results by employee ID
I am running in Windows on an 4-core i7 processor

a) for each employee record
b) for each test
c) run the test
d) log the test results
next test
next employee

QUESTIONS:

- Should (a) be multithreaded because it's reading an employee record from a database (I/O bound)?
- Should (b) be multithreaded because it's reading a test record from a database (I/O bound)?
- Should (c) be multiprocessed because it's reading/writing in memory (CPU bound)?
- Should (d) be multithreaded because it's writing to a database (I/O bound)?

### My current code is something like this:

```
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process
import sqlite3

connection=sqlite3.connect('EmpTestPython.db', timeout=90)
cursor=connection.cursor()

def ForEachEmp(empId, msg):
    print(f'    ForEachEmp -> {empId}')    
    
    testProcs=[]
    for testId in range(1, 11): # actual testId numbers will come from DB
        print(f'        ForEachTest -> {empId} {testId}')
        testProc=Process(target=ForEachTest, args=(empId, testId, ''))
        testProc.start()    
    for p in testProcs:
        p.join()      

def ForEachTest(empId, testId, msg):
    print(f'            Launching testId {testId} for emp {empId}')
    testCode = GetCode(testId)
    testDate = datetime.datetime.now
    result = Eval(testCode)
    cursor.execute(
        '''insert into TestResults
        (TestDate, EmpId, TestId, Result)
        values(?, ?, ?, ?)''',
        (testDate, empId, testId, result))
    connection.commit()

def GetCode(testId):
    # this is example-only code    
    cursor.execute('''SELECT TestCode FROM Tests WHERE ID={testId}''')
    return TestCode
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    empProcs=[]
    for empId in range(1, 51): # actual empId numbers will come from DB
        print(f'Launching empId {empId}')
        empProc=Process(target=ForEachEmp, args=(empId, ''))
        empProc.start()
        empProcs.append(empProc)
    for p in empProcs:
        p.join()
```

Comment: If you are nesting loops then the outermost loop is the logical place to use multiple processes. If you have `n` records and `m` processes then give each process a batch of `n/m` records to work on.

Comment: We *cannot* answer the question without *profiling* information or hardware information. Whether a task is compute bound or IO bound is dependent of the hardware. For example, HDD can be 10x-1000x slower than SSD. If the OS can cache the DB in memory, then it can be 10-1000x faster. Seek time of an HDD is measured in dozens of milliseconds while the DRAM latency is measured in dozens of nanoseconds. A factor of 1000000 make a huge difference. Not to mention this is difficult to predict the speed of your computation.

Comment: Note that memory-bound tasks are often not CPU-bound. The former tends not to scale as opposed to the later. Without more information, I advise you to try multithreading, then run the code and profile it. If you see that the computation is compute-bound on your machine (likely not), then use multiprocessing.

Comment: First, thank you for your *very* prompt replies! My first intuition is to multiprocess everything and let the OS figure it out. After some reading, I see where that can actually lead to slower execution (process marshalling overhead and all that). In fact, in Task Manager - Performance, my CPU shows nearly 100% and disk I/O does too. I will use Multiprocessing for the outer loop, as suggested, and Multithreading for the rest and see how that goes. Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, here's a link to the Performance screen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_hsYFyjc_dD50-vB6XkoPKbxoyXlsxDC/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: A database should be able to cope with multiple connections reading records in the same table(s) simultaneously. If different threads are updating the same database records, then the updates will be serialised. Locking might affect how you choose to update the database with test results.

Comment: Thanks, is suspected as much. The individual threads will be updating different records so there should be no contention.